# Backup files from Terminal in Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, terminal, data-recovery

I want to transfer files in Recovery Mode https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314. I opened Terminal in Recovery Mode and tried to copy files to external hard drive. I use this code

```
// I used cd .. to get to the topmost folder
cd Volumes // takes me to volumes
ls
cd OS\ X\ Base\ System
ls
```

The problem is that this creates a loop. Upon cd-ing to OS\ X\ Base\ System it takes me back to the start, namely the `/` folder that contains `Volumes`. I want to copy the whole Document directory and Desktop directory. What I am doing wrong?

EDIT>

When I first enter the Terminal, I am in `private/var/root/Library`, the system created a var folder when figuring out something is missing I guess.

Comment: By "takes you back to the start", which path is this? I am assuming `/` because you begin with `Volumes` as a relative path.

Comment: root folder. the one that contains Volumes

Comment: Are there other folders listed in `/Volumes`? Otherwise you may need to run Disk Utility first (it's in one of the menus) and mount the main drive there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `cd OS\ X\ Base\ System` takes you back to `/`? I suggest you follow @patrix's suggestion of mounting the main disk through Disk Utility. If you need to use the command line, `diskutil mount /dev/disk0s2` (assuming disk0s2 is your main partition).

Comment: Other folders are .Trashes, The external hard drive I have connected. yes, it takes me back to /. I deleted private/var folder. All hell broke loose since then. Thats why I am doing a recovery of files.

Comment: When booted to OS X Recovery the _root_ of the Macintosh HD is not `/`, it's `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My goal was to copy files to the external hard drive. They are stored in Macintosh HD (I originally thought I will find Macintosh HD in a subfolder of OS X Base System - wrong assumption). There was no Macintosh HD in Volumes folder, because I first needed to unlock it (I use FileVault).

First you need to find the lvUUID of your Macintosh HD. Use this command:

```
diskutil list // lvUUID
```

Look for text looking similar to this:

```
Logical Volume on disk0s2 
4B2EFAAE-C871-4E6D-AB15-2DDE604B97CE // this is lvUUID
Unlocked Encrypted
```

To unlock use this command:

```
diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID #replace lvUUID by the one shown in the diskutil listing
```

You will be prompted with password for your user account.
After that Macintosh HD will be present in `/Volumes/` folder.

All thanks to [klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) for enlightening me. See full Q&A here: [No Macintosh HD in Volumes folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236210/no-macintosh-hd-in-volumes-folder)

Comment: THANK YOU !!!! AHHH!!! I had a problem with kernel extension causing me to not be able to boot at all, and of course there was no easy visible way in recovery mode to mount my root fs, but this worked perfectly and was able to fix everything, THANK YOU THANK YOU AHHHH!!!!!

Comment: If anybody need the tutorial it's at this link: https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-mac-osx-stuckhanging-on-progress-bar-will-not-boot/

Comment: You can also mount your hard drive from disk utility, then open terminal and cd to it

Answer (score 17):

For new macs using disks with APFS (Apple file system) you can simply do:

```
diskutil apfs unlock "Macintosh HD"
```

And then access it by:

```
ls "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"
```

Comment: Worked great for [deleting system protected installation file, in a secure way](https://www.iosappsandhacks.com/cant-remove-install-macos-high-sierra-app-fix). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When booted to OS X Recovery the *root* of the Macintosh HD is not `/`, it's: 
 `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/`

To get to your Home directory in Terminal, use:

```
cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/User_Name"
```

Where `User_Name` is the name of your User Account.

From there you can access your directories such as Documents, Desktop, Pictures, etc.

---

When booting into the Recovery Partition, the Macintosh HD does get mounted automatically and should be listed in `/Volumes`. If this is not the case, run Disk Utility (accessible through one of the menus in Recovery Mode) first to check the drive for errors and have them fixed.

Comment: upon ls-ing the folder it first throws me into when I open Terminal I can see that there is no Volumes, just .Forward and Library. I also edited my question with the result of pwd command executed right after opening the Terminal.

Comment: @sanjihan, It doesn't matter what directory you're in when starting Terminal in OS X Recovery!  You have to navigate to where you want to be and the information I've presented in my answer re: `cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/User_Name"` worked for me when booting into OS X Recovery.  If your internal startup volume was not named Macintosh HD then change the command to what's appropriate.

Comment: Agree with you! Buy there is no Macintosh HD in Volumes. just OS X Base System and .Trashes. I thought that OS X Base System is a parent of Macintosh HD. Just found out it isnt. I will procede with First Aid on Macintosh HD. Mybe that will list it in Volumes

Comment: @sanjihan, If you quit Terminal and go into Disk Utility, do you see your Macintosh HD?

Comment: yes I do, but it is greyed out. I ran First Aid on APPLE SSD which is a parent folder of Macintosh HD.

Comment: @sanjihan, It's probably grayed out because it's not mounted, have you tried mounting it with Disk Utility?