# No Macintosh HD in Volumes folder

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility

I am running in recovery mode to save the data from disk( I cant login due to deletion of private/var folder). I opened `Terminal` and went to `Volumes`. This folder should be populated with the `Macintosh HD` subfolder. It isn't. It just lists the `OS X Base System, the external hard drive I have connected and .Trashes`. I ran First Aid on Macintosh HD Parent folder called APPLE SSD... in Disk Utility panel. Nothing changed. How can I copy the data if there is no Macintosh HD to navigate to?

This is the output from `diskutil list`

[image]

Comment: Can you please open Terminal, run `diskutil list` and add a picture of the output to the question?

Comment: I added a screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main volume is encrypted with FileVault and still locked – consequently it doesn't show up in /Volumes. Before being able to mount it you'd have to unlock it:

```
diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID #replace lvUUID by the one shown in the diskutil listing
```

You will then be asked to enter the passphrase/password. You have to enter a passphrase or a password of a regular user eligible of unlocking FileVault. In your example the lvUUID is shown in `diskutil list` and starts with 573…. You may also get the lvUUID by entering `diskutil cs list`.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure, I replace the lvUUID with the 573.. and than get a prompt for typing in password? or just type password after 573...

Comment: @sanjihan You will get a pw prompt

Comment: I am successfully copying files with cp -r command. Thank you! Is there a way to know when files had finished copying? (except for listening for hard drive spinning sound to stop)

Comment: @sanjihan You will get a new prompt if no error occurs! Better use `rsync ...`! rsync allows to add an option to show the progress.